# Bending a line (path) with CSS & JS?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

i want to draw a simple horizontal line and make an animation where this line bends. I have a video of this animation. Can you give me some advice how to start and which js/css I have to use?

It's all about the line on the bottom of the rect:
http://www.stop-stottern.de/fileadmin/user_upload/clips/Zwerchfell.avi.3GP

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that Raphael would be my choice:http://raphaeljs.com/  POWEEEEERFUL! :)

Answer (score 1):

you need scalar graphics to draw lines/curves. That can be done with the framework RaphaelJS.

Answer (score 1):

If your clients support HTML5 you could always use a [canvas](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/)? If not then I second Raphael, its a great tool.

Comment: i thought about using html5 because the app will only run on new webkit browser (android, ios, safari, chrome etc.). any links regarding canvas?

Comment: I have no experience with canvas (wish I had!) so I can't recommend a library or tutorial I'm afraid. Please let us know if you find something that works well for you.